# Parsing JSON with multiple arrays and comparing values with Excel data using Python 3.6

Tags: python, excel

I have a JSON like:

```
{
"results": [{
    "data": {
        "child": [{
            "sex": "2",
            "birthDateReliability": "0",
            "applicationInternalIdentifier": "cmpclt",
            "birthDate": "2016-07-04",
            "firstName": "Anna"
        }],
        "consumerType": "PRIVATE",
        "countryCode": "FR",
        "initialAppSourceCode": "ABCDWEB",
        "optin": [{
            "optinSourceApplication": "ABCDWEB",
            "acceptanceDate": "2017-02-10T10:14:55.037Z",
            "marketingGroupService": "XYZXYX-ABC"
        }, {
            "optinSourceApplication": "ABCDWEB",
            "acceptanceDate": "2017-02-10T10:14:55.037Z",
            "marketingGroupService": "XYZXYX-DEF"
        }, {
            "optinSourceApplication": "ABCDWEB",
            "acceptanceDate": "2017-02-10T10:14:55.037Z",
            "marketingGroupService": "XYZXYX-GHI"
        }, {
            "optinSourceApplication": "ABCDWEB",
            "acceptanceDate": "2017-02-10T10:14:55.037Z",
            "marketingGroupService": "XYZXYX-JKL"
        }, {
            "optinSourceApplication": "ABCDWEB",
            "acceptanceDate": "2017-02-10T10:14:55.037Z",
            "marketingGroupService": "XYZXYX-MNO"
        }],
        "didsys_KGexample": true,
        "addressLine1": "123 Street",
        "marketCode": "10107"
    },
    "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1486721887742,
    "socialProviders": "site",
    "password": {
        "hashSettings": {
            "rounds": 9504778,
            "salt": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "algorithm": "xyz"
        },
        "hash": "$AF$$$F$$$$$ZX$$$$$J$--"
    },
    "iRank": 0,
    "created": "2017-02-10T10:15:36.814Z",
    "lastLoginTimestamp": 1486721736970,
    "oldestDataUpdated": "2017-02-10T10:15:36.861Z",
    "isLockedOut": false,
    "profile": {
        "zip": "12345",
        "lastName": "Shah",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "locale": "en",
        "firstName": "Jiten",
        "city": "London"
    },
    "isVerified": false,
    "createdTimestamp": 1486721736814,
    "identities": [{
        "lastName": "Shah",
        "zip": "12345",
        "isLoginIdentity": true,
        "locale": "en",
        "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1486721887742,
        "lastUpdated": "2017-02-10T10:18:07.742Z",
        "provider": "site",
        "allowsLogin": true,
        "isExpiredSession": false,
        "providerUID": "jbx63a0ed2f9a1cfa8cgh7dsdsl3",
        "city": "London",
        "oldestDataUpdatedTimestamp": 1486721736861,
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "oldestDataUpdated": "2017-02-10T10:15:36.861Z",
        "firstName": "Jiten"
    }],
    "lastUpdated": "2017-02-10T10:18:07.742Z",
    "emails": {
        "unverified": ["abc@gmail.com"],
        "verified": []
    },
    "isRegistered": true,
    "regSource": "https://abcn.net/user/register",
    "lastLoginLocation": {
        "state": "H9",
        "coordinates": {
            "lon": -0.0930938720703125,
            "lat": 51.51420593261719
        },
        "country": "GB",
        "city": "London"
    },
    "isActive": true,
    "lastLogin": "2017-02-10T10:15:36.970Z",
    "oldestDataUpdatedTimestamp": 1486721736861,
    "UID": "ed9af442a4a7bd63a08a1cfa8c9d02f9",
    "registered": "2017-02-10T10:18:07.993Z",
    "rbaPolicy": {
        "riskPolicyLocked": false
    },
    "loginIDs": {
        "unverifiedEmails": [],
        "emails": ["abc@gmail.com"]
    },
    "registeredTimestamp": 1486721887993,
    "loginProvider": "site"
}],
"objectsCount": 1,
"totalCount": 1,
"statusCode": 200,
"errorCode": 0,
"statusReason": "OK",
"callId": "5164e6c985ee4ed9bcd76ebd403cfaaa",
"time": "2017-02-14T14:24:26.487Z"
}
```

I have maintained the Excel sheet where I have maintained all the above JSON Key/Values in two columns.
Now I want to compare/Validate all the values from Excel Sheet against key/value of above JSON file using Python 3.6.

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the question :)

Comment: I need to read the above Json and compare the values like "birthDateReliability","initialAppSourceCode", "marketingGroupService" with the excel where in I have stored all the json keys as one column and their values in the another column.
Hope this helps.